# Arrayformula returning FALSE instead of specified value_if_false

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I have a formula that is returning FALSE values when the conditions are not met, rather than the "" blank cell that I specified. I'm pretty new to using formulas, so I'm wondering what I can do to get all these FALSE cells to display as blank instead.

Here's my formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(if($B$2 = 'Inventory Form Responses'!$B$2:$B,if('Inventory Form Responses'!$E$2:$E <> "",B5-'Inventory Form Responses'!$E$2:$E,"")))
```

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

There are two `IF` formulas and hence requires two `""`

```
 =ARRAYFORMULA(if($B$2 = 'Inventory Form Responses'!$B$2:$B,if('Inventory Form Responses'!$E$2:$E <> "",B5-'Inventory Form Responses'!$E$2:$E,""), ""))
```